# How do i fix conversion error in the following code?

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion, copy-constructor

I have a template class:

```
template<class T>
class A{
  T a, b;
  public:
  A(A<T> const & o) : a(o.a), b(o.b){}
  A(T const & _a, T const & _b) : a(_a), b(_b){}
};

A<double> d(1.2, 4.5);
A<float> f = d; //error: conversion from A<double> to non-scalar type A<float> requested
```

How do i define a conversion function for my class?
My compiler is g++ 4.7.0

Comment: Your trying to place a double in a float spot

Comment: you probably don't want to be converting to lower precision type in real code

Comment: @MateuszKowalczyk, you're right. That's just a test program i wrote as i am learning templates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make a template constructor:

```
template<class T>
class A{
    T a, b;
public:

    template<class U>
    A(A<U> const & rhs) : a(rhs.a), b(rhs.b) {}

    A(T const & _a, T const & _b) : a(_a), b(_b){}
};
```

Then you should be able to convert any class `A<U>` to any class `A<T>` as long as `U` is convertible to `T`.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is not a good idea.
However, to get over the compiler error, you can specialize the class -

```
template <>
class A<float>
{
    public:
    A(A<double> const & o) {}
};
```